# GLKview vs GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am building a native OpenGL application for both Android & IOS. The OpenGL code is the same on both platforms. For Android I am rendering my scene using GLSurfaceView and for IOS I am using GLKView.

I am setting up the application to use on-demand-rendering. I monitor touch input on the screen as fast the OS notifies me and then I make updates to the OpenGL scene with each notification. On Android I update my OpenGL scene with GLSurfaceView.requesetRender() and on IOS I update my OpenGL scene with GLKView.update().

In my tests I have found that IOS & Android (on a variety of devices) all send touch updates every 0.016 seconds. This makes sense as this is 60fps and is in line with the standard 60Hz displays on these devices.

Where I am puzzled is in the difference in times it takes to render the exact same OpenGL scene on IOS & Android (on a variety of devices). On almost all Android devices I am able to render my entire scene in 0.015 seconds on average. On IOS devices it takes 0.034 seconds on average (over two times as long).

Can I blame this completely on GPU hardware in the Android phones vs IOS phones or is there some fine-tuning required for the GLKView that I need to implement?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: This question is way too broad without adding any data on what you are doing or what parts take that long. It could be your measurement is incorrect, it might be hardware, it might be software or anything in between. I must say though that I would if possible avoid GLK at all cost (except the C part of it which basically means matrix and vector tools).

Comment: I know it is broad but it supposed to be. The OpenGL specific code is the exact same. There is some macro that is acting differently.

Comment: I see what you mean but unfortunately it is not as trivial. To check the speed you need remember the start date before you begin with calls to openGL, then call all you need and then perform glFinish to ensure all was complete by your GPU, then get the end date and compute the duration. Anything else will most likely result in hitting some locking mechanisms which give you incorrect results. And even this one assumes you are not working with some large data transfer to the GPU which may be optimized with buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you that you are targeting 30fps on iOS. [Link to GLKViewController's preferredFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit/glkviewcontroller/1620702-preferredframespersecond).

> Your application should choose a frame rate that it can consistently maintain.
>
> The default value is 30 frames per second

Comment: I am not using the CADisplayLink functionality however. I am simply rendering on demand. No point in rendering out the OpenGL scene if there isn't a reason to.